# querying a table to get the name of other table from a field to perform a final query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to accomplish this? A query that can get a table name from a field in another table and condense all columns of that table to one line of key:val; pair. (There will only be one determined from the assoc table ft_data_id)

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0c27

```
ID  FT_ID   FT_DATA_ID  NAME        TABLE                   DATA
1   1       1           one         features_data_one       ro_one: A; ro_two: B
2   2       1           two         features_data_two       rt_two: C; rt_two: D



/****** list of features with the name and the table the data lies in */
CREATE TABLE features (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        `table` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO features(name, `table`) VALUES ('one', 'features_data_one');
INSERT INTO features(name, `table`) VALUES ('two', 'features_data_two');


/****** feature one */
CREATE TABLE features_data_one (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        ro_one VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        ro_two VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO features_data_one (ro_one, ro_two) VALUES ('A', 'B');



/****** feature two */
CREATE TABLE features_data_two (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        rt_one VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        rt_two VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO features_data_two (rt_one, rt_two) VALUES ('C', 'D');

/****** association table which links a feature with a feature_id. The feature_id is the id in a specific table. This table is specificed in the feature table. */
CREATE TABLE assoc (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        ft_id INT NOT NULL,
        ft_data_id INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO assoc (ft_id, ft_data_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO assoc (ft_id, ft_data_id) VALUES (2, 1);


SELECT * 
FROM assoc a
INNER JOIN features as ft ON a.ft_id = ft.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho, you are trying to make something strange and very unnatural to SQL.

Why don't you try to create the only single table?

```
CREATE TABLE features_all (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        feature_name varchar(20) not null,
        ro_one VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        ro_two VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        index(feature_name)
);
INSERT INTO features_all (feature_name, ro_one, ro_two) values
('one', 'A', '1'),
('one', 'C', '31'),
('one', 'Z', '71'),
('two', 'A', '1'),
('two', 'S', '12'),
('two', 'D', '14');
```

This style helps to populate features (add the third one, etc). Just insert new rows!
No need to create tables!

I don't know your case, but sometimes it is useful to replace

```
        index(feature_name)
```

with

```
        unique(feature_name, ro_one)
```

to ensure you'll get the only one value for any key in selected feature

Comment: hi v.sheldeshov, this was just an example the reason is that there could be 100 different tables each with different columns.

Comment: Ok, but consider merging all these 100 tables into one.

Comment: Not quite sure, but the fack ot choosing the right tablename to join based on the value of an attribute voilates 5NF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form